# SQL Cleanup Help - Creating columns based off other column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relatively large dataset I am working with - I am trying to create new columns within that table based on other column entries.

For example, I have two columns named Feature and FeatureValue. Within Feature exist different features i.e Eyes, nose, mouth etc. I am trying to make each unique value in the Feature column a new column with corresponding entries from the FeatureValue. To explain, if row 43 held the value 'Eyes' in Feature and and 'Blue' in FeatureValue - I would want Eyes as a column header and Blue as an entry.

I appreciate any help greatly!

Comment: MySQL (and many other databases) do this ([EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)) badly because its not conducive to the SQL language. What you are asking for comes under the name "pivot tables" and is also messy. Consider keeping attributes as column headers and values in the row associated with the entity.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

I making a bit of a guess as to why you want to do this operation - I'm assuming you need to speed up a query that gets the values for a particular feature. If this is for performance, then there are probably better solutions than this, but here we go...

If I understand correctly, you want a list of all the values for each feature. I'm not sure your result makes sense as a table, however. To play with this, let's start with an example data set in a table we will call `Features`.

```
Feature  | FeatureValue
-----------------------
Eyes     | Blue
Nose     | Potato
Eyes     | brown
Eyes     | blue
Eyes     | brown
Nose     | pointy
```

What it sounds like you want is a resulting table that transforms this one:

```
Eyes     | Nose
------------------
Blue     | Potato
brown    | pointy
blue     |
```

This doesn't make much sense as a table, because there is no relationship between items that share a row. I expect you are trying to optimize queries to get those lists.

So first, a little SQL that will get the list of values for each feature:

```
SELECT Feature, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT FeatureValue) AS `Values` FROM Features GROUP BY Feature;
```

This will return the same result as the second table, but sideways:

```
Feature | Values
-------------------------
Eyes    | Blue,brown,blue
Nose    | Potato,pointy
```

If you consult the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), you will see that you can specify the delimiter in the list, the order of the list, and a couple of other tings. You may also want to peruse the other GROUP_BY methods, in case I misunderstood what your goal is.

For performance you could cache this query periodically - I'm not sure how often you planned to rebuild your lists.

If you really need this to be a table with columns, that gets trickier, and to be honest is probably done much more easily in code than developing a single query.